# How to search an element of an array and display

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I need to display the grade each student has by asking for it's number. The grade each student has is tied with each student, can be the array place of each. The Student number is what is prompted to ask the search in the array. Could it possibly be done in a short Two liner?

```
using System;

using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
string[] studentName = {"Bob","Marie","Nathan","Lois","Sam"};
string[] studentsNumber = {"040707701","040707702","040707703","040707704","040707705"};
string[] studentGrade = {"A","B","C","D","F"};

string studentsNumber = "";
Console.WriteLine("What is your student number");
Console.ReadLine(studentsNumber.ToString());
for(int index = 0, studentNumber[studentNumber - 1], index++)
{
Console.WriteLine(studentsNumber[index]);
onsole.WriteLine(studentName[],studentGrade[] {0} {1});
}
       }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a `Student` class and keeping all related data there? Inside properties like `Name`, `Id`, `Grade`? The way you are doing it right now will work also (having each property in its own array), but is much harder to work with.

Comment: Yeah, I should change that now, this was taken off the whiteboard and I couldn't figure this out. Its neither assignment nor quiz.

Comment: Please fix your code snippet, it's full of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be much better to have an object:

```
public class StudentInfo
{
   public string Name {get; set;} 
   public string Grade {get; set;} 
   public int Number {get; set;} 
}
```

And then have a `List<StudentInfo>`.

By doing it this way your data will be tight together.  Otherwise you might end up in a situation where you have different number of items in each array and you wouldn-t know which one is which.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is homework, I'm not going to give you the answer outright but give you a hint instead.

Once you have the student number, loop through the array of student numbers. Once you find the index of the matching number...you can use that to retrieve the grade.

Keep in mind, though, that arrays aren't the right way to solve this problem at all. You'd be much better off creating a class for student that included name, number, and grade. You could then create instances of the class and add those instances to a List that you could then iterate through.

Comment: It's likely that if he's having problems with this, he's not taking a data structures course.

Comment: How is this loop done, is the above relatively in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

eek!

Why not use an anonymous class with a bit of linq?

```
var students = new[]
{
    new { Name = "Bob", Number = "040707701", Grade = "A" },
    ...
};

var grade = students.Where(s => s.Number == "040707701").Select(s => s.Grade);
```